# Visual studio database project two way synonyms

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project

We have few databases running together, with synonyms between them. There're also two way synonyms between the databases. VS database projects can't seem to handle these. Two way synonyms don't work in VS, I can only reference another database in VS one way, otherwise there's circular reference. I tried creating a snapshot of the database project in VS but to be able to take a snapshot I need to build the project, to be able to build the project I need to reference the other database project which doesn't compile because it doesn't recognise synonyms, etc. It seems multiple databases (same server) with two way synonyms on each other is too complicated for VS to manage. Has anyone managed to get something like this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SQLPackage command line to create the dacpac (it's a bit more forgiving of the cross-database references than the GUI). Add those as DB references.

There's a section here about using SQLPackage to extract the dacpac from an existing database.
http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2012/10/ssdt-importing-existing-database.html

I've written about external references here:
http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2012/10/ssdt-external-database-references.html

We have a lot of cross-DB dependencies and once we get past the initial builds or start from a restored DB, we don't have any issues w/ the references.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had a look at that but both databases keep changing, if I create a dacpac, it'll be out of date after a few days, with new tables, views, maybe synonyms, etc. How do you handle that?

Comment: I had a look at your blogs earlier today actually, well written but maybe need to read all of them. But yeah, spent a few hours on this but there're about 8 databases on the server, all referencing each other, but just can't get the solution to build. I considered the dacpac solution from your blogs, but the dacpac will be out of date after a couple days.

Comment: You'll need to keep the dacpacs in sync. As you build/change your projects, copy the output dacpac into your shared folder. It's not hard and I find it's not needed nearly as often as you'd think unless you're constantly referencing those new/changed objects. Even then, we have several of our DB projects with 5-6 references to dacpac files.

Comment: OK, thanks Peter, I'll have a more in depth look at your blogs. but yeah can't create the dacpac because it references other projects which don't compile, to be able to compile I need the dacpac, etc. goes in a circle. Do you reckon the effort is worth it? Currently we use the database project only for keeping track of the changes so we have a history but I'd like to automate the process so I can generate .sql from differences to run on the production DB. If you ever happen to be in Sydney, you're welcome to have a look at our projects, you'll love it :)

Comment: I've found it quite worth it. One set of "the truth" for what the DB should be and it just makes it that way (with option to gen/review scripts). If you use sqlpackage.exe to gen the dacpacs to start, you don't need the other projects to compile immediately. Once the references are in place they should compile without too much trouble. If you start by adding the references to the project, then importing it might go a bit easier as well. I know that getting past the circular references was the hardest part for us. :)